# How to generate the materialized value from the elements in Source or Flow?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Suppose there is a source of type `Source[Int, NotUsed]`. How can this be turned into a `Source[Int, T]` where the materialized value `T` is computed based on the elements of the source?

Example: I would like summing the elements from a stream; how to implement `dumbFlow` so result should be 6 instead of 42?

```
val dumbFlow = ??? //Flow[Int].mapMaterializedValue(_ => 42)

//code below cannot be changed
val source = Source(List(1, 2, 3)).viaMat(dumbFlow)(Keep.right)
val result = source.toMat(Sink.ignore)(Keep.left).run() 
//result: Int = 42
```

I know how to achieve the same result using `Sink.fold` or `Sink.head` but I need the materialization logic in the `Source`; cannot change `.to(Sink.ignore)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the materialized value is always computed (including any `mapMaterializedValue`/`toMat`/`viaMat` etc.) before a single element goes through the stream and thus cannot depend on the elements of the stream.

If the materialized value happens to be a `Future` (in the Scala API), the future can be constructed (though not yet completed) and the stream can complete the `Future` based on the elements.  In general, the `Future` materialized values are from sinks (e.g., as you note `Sink.fold`/`Sink.head`).

The `alsoTo` operator on a `Source` or `Flow` lets you embed a `Sink` to the side of a `Source`/`Flow`.  It has an `alsoToMat` companion which lets you combine the `Sink`'s materialized value with the `Source`/`Flow`'s.

So one could have

```scala
val summingSink = Sink.fold[Int, Int](0)(_ + _)
val dumbFlow: Flow[Int, Int, Future[Int]] = Flow[Int].alsoToMat(summingSink)(Keep.right)
```

```scala
val result: Future[Int] = source.toMat(Sink.ignore)(Keep.left).run()
```

```scala
result.foreach(println _)
// will eventually print 6
```